# Order properties should not be accessed directly - WooCommerce 3.0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've just upgraded my local WooCommerce website to 3.0. Everything works perfectly as normal, but I've noticed with debugging turned on that I'm getting hundreds of the following notices:

`[05-Apr-2017 12:25:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  id was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Please see <a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4137`

So it looks like WooCommerce are pulling back being able to directly call order data. One example this code is being triggered by is this function in my functions.php file:

```
function eden_woocommerce_order_number($original, $order)
{
    return 'EDN-' . str_pad($order->id, 10, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

This function simply adds "EDN" to the start of the order ID and pads it by 10 characters, but WooCommerce doesn't like how I'm calling `$order` - what would be the best way to rewrite such a function that 3.0 is happy with?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

it says "id was called **incorrectly**. Order properties should not be accessed directly."

Try `$order->get_id()`

Comment: Correct, this appeared to fix the problem. Also, I was incorrectly calling order data such as `$data = get_post_meta($order_id)`. Instead, I changed this to `$data = new WC_Order($order_id);` and called the necessary functions via that method, for example: `$data->get_billing_address_2();`.

Comment: Any idea if this is backward compatible with WC 2.6.x?

Comment: @bret i read some good examples on the WooCommerce Blog e.g.
https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/wc-2-7-extension-compatibility-examples/

Answer (score 20):

Maybe its helpful for others too. Here's the some stuff regarding to all the functions of directly accessed values through the magic function.

**This function is from Woocommerce 3.0**

```
if ( 'completed_date' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_date_completed() ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->get_date_completed()->getOffsetTimestamp() ) : '';
    } elseif ( 'paid_date' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_date_paid() ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->get_date_paid()->getOffsetTimestamp() ) : '';
    } elseif ( 'modified_date' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_date_modified() ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->get_date_modified()->getOffsetTimestamp() ) : '';
    } elseif ( 'order_date' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_date_created() ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->get_date_created()->getOffsetTimestamp() ) : '';
    } elseif ( 'id' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_id();
    } elseif ( 'post' === $key ) {
        return get_post( $this->get_id() );
    } elseif ( 'status' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_status();
    } elseif ( 'post_status' === $key ) {
        return get_post_status( $this->get_id() );
    } elseif ( 'customer_message' === $key || 'customer_note' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_customer_note();
    } elseif ( in_array( $key, array( 'user_id', 'customer_user' ) ) ) {
        return $this->get_customer_id();
    } elseif ( 'tax_display_cart' === $key ) {
        return get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' );
    } elseif ( 'display_totals_ex_tax' === $key ) {
        return 'excl' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' );
    } elseif ( 'display_cart_ex_tax' === $key ) {
        return 'excl' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' );
    } elseif ( 'cart_discount' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_total_discount();
    } elseif ( 'cart_discount_tax' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_discount_tax();
    } elseif ( 'order_tax' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_cart_tax();
    } elseif ( 'order_shipping_tax' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_shipping_tax();
    } elseif ( 'order_shipping' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_shipping_total();
    } elseif ( 'order_total' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_total();
    } elseif ( 'order_type' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_type();
    } elseif ( 'order_currency' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_currency();
    } elseif ( 'order_version' === $key ) {
        return $this->get_version();
    } elseif ( is_callable( array( $this, "get_{$key}" ) ) ) {
        return $this->{"get_{$key}"}();
    } else {
        return get_post_meta( $this->get_id(), '_' . $key, true );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the woo get function. add `get_     ()`

For example, change:
`$order->status` to `$order->get_status()`