# Woocommerce payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm stuck and wondering that someone can help me, I have a Woocommerce payment gateway with Armenian banks and it doesn't work in a new versions of Woocommerce.

**The error is:** *order_total was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly*.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class WC_ArCa extends WC_Payment_Gateway

{

    private $environment;



    private $username;



    private $password;



    /**

     * WC_ArCa constructor.

     */

    function __construct()

    {

        $this->id = "arca";



        // The Title shown on the top of the Payment Gateways Page next to all the other Payment Gateways

        $this->method_title = __("ArCa", 'ArCa');



        // The description for this Payment Gateway, shown on the actual Payment options page on the backend

        $this->method_description = __("Description", 'ArCa payment gateway');



        // The title to be used for the vertical tabs that can be ordered top to bottom

        $this->title = __("Title", 'ArCa');



        // If you want to show an image next to the gateway's name on the frontend, enter a URL to an image.

        $this->icon = null;



        // Bool. Can be set to true if you want payment fields to show on the checkout

        // if doing a direct integration, which we are doing in this case

        $this->has_fields = true;



        // This basically defines your settings which are then loaded with init_settings()

        $this->init_form_fields();



        // After init_settings() is called, you can get the settings and load them into variables, e.g:

        // $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );

        $this->init_settings();



        // True if test mode is enabled

        $this->environment = $this->settings['environment'];



        // ArCa username

        $this->username = $this->settings['username'];



        // ArCa password

        $this->password = $this->settings['password'];



        // Lets check for SSL

        //add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'do_ssl_check'));



        // Save settings

        if (is_admin()) {

            // Versions over 2.0

            // Save our administration options. Since we are not going to be doing anything special

            // we have not defined 'process_admin_options' in this class so the method in the parent

            // class will be used instead

            add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array(

                $this,

                'process_admin_options'

            ));

        }

    }



    // Build the administration fields for this specific Gateway

    public function init_form_fields()

    {

        $this->form_fields = array(

            'enabled' => array(

                'title' => __('Enable / Disable', 'arca'),

                'label' => __('Enable this payment gateway', 'arca'),

                'type' => 'checkbox',

                'default' => 'yes',

            ),

            'title' => array(

                'title' => __('Title', 'arca'),

                'type' => 'text',

                'desc_tip' => __('Payment title the customer will see during the checkout process.', 'arca'),

                'default' => __('card', 'arca'),

            ),

            'description' => array(

                'title' => __('Description', 'arca'),

                'type' => 'textarea',

                'desc_tip' => __('Payment description the customer will see during the checkout process.', 'arca'),

                'default' => __('Pay securely using your credit card.', 'arca'),

                'css' => 'max-width:350px;'

            ),

            'username' => array(

                'title' => __('Username', 'username'),

                'type' => 'text',

                'desc_tip' => __('Username description.', 'username'),

            ),

            'password' => array(

                'title' => __('Password', 'password'),

                'type' => 'password',

                'desc_tip' => __('Password description.', 'password'),

            ),

            'environment' => array(

                'title' => __('ArCa Test Mode', 'arca'),

                'label' => __('Enable Test Mode', 'arca'),

                'type' => 'checkbox',

                'description' => __('Place the payment gateway in test mode.', 'arca'),

                'default' => 'yes',

            )

        );

    }



    /**

     * Submit payment and handle response

     *

     * @param int $order_id

     * @throws Exception

     *

     * @return mixed

     */

    public function process_payment($order_id)

    {

        // Get this Order's information so that we know

        // who to charge and how much

        $customer_order = new wc_get_order( $order_id );



        // Are we testing right now or is it a real transaction

        $environment = ($this->environment == "yes") ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';



        // Decide which URL to post to

        $environment_url = ("FALSE" == $environment)

            ? 'https://ipay.arca.am/payment/rest/'

            : 'https://ipaytest.arca.am:8445/payment/rest';



        // This is where the fun stuff begins

        $payload = array(

            "userName" => $this->username,

            "password" => $this->password,

            "amount" => intval($customer_order->order_total) * 100,

            "returnUrl" => $this->get_return_url($customer_order),

            "orderNumber" => intval($customer_order->get_order_number()) + 119332,

        );



        // Send this payload to Authorize.net for processing

        $response = wp_remote_post($environment_url . "registerPreAuth.do", array(

            'method' => 'POST',

            'body' => http_build_query($payload),

            'timeout' => 90,

            'sslverify' => false,

        ));





        if (is_wp_error($response)) {

           throw new Exception(__('We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.', 'arca'));

        }



        if (empty($response['body'])) {

            throw new Exception(__('ArCa\'s Response was empty.', 'arca'));

        }



        // Retrieve the body's response if no errors found

        $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

        $response_data = json_decode($response_body, true);



        if (isset($response_data["errorCode"]) && isset($response_data["formUrl"])) {

            if ($response_data["errorCode"] == 0) {

                return array(

                    'result' => 'success',

                    'redirect' => $response_data['formUrl'],

                );

            } else {

                throw new Exception(__($response_data["errorMessage"], 'arca'));

            }

        }



        throw new Exception(__("Error processing checkout, please try again.", 'arca'));

    }

}
```

Comment: You just need to replace this line: `"amount" => intval($customer_order->order_total) * 100,` by this one `"amount" => intval( $customer_order->get_total() ) * 100,` … That's all…

Comment: Loic is correct, but in a more general sense as of WC3.0 object properties cannot be access directly. This means `$object->property` is no longer allowed and you need to use the class' setters/getters such as `$object->get_propery()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order properties should not be accessed directly - WooCommerce 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231684/order-properties-should-not-be-accessed-directly-woocommerce-3-0)