# Trying to understand a php warning in my Apache error log

Tags: php, apache, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have an error in my Apache error.log file which I am trying to understand. Our WooCommerce driven sites are connected to an electronic warehouse system that manages our inventory and orders. I login into the system, DEAR, and use **their** integration to connect back to my store. It sets uses a REST API and creates two webhooks, order creation and order modified. Ok, that's the background. Now the warning: rather than be one line I've tried to break it out logically.

```
[Tue Mar 02 00:32:43 2021] [warn] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] mod_fcgid: stderr: id was called incorrectly.
Order properties should not be accessed directly. 
Backtrace: 
require('wp-blog-header.php'),
wp, WP->main, 
WP->parse_request,
do_action_ref_array('parse_request'),
WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
rest_api_loaded, WP_REST_Server->serve_request,
WP_REST_Server->dispatch,
WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request,
WC_REST_CRUD_Controller->get_items,
WC_REST_Orders_V2_Controller->prepare_object_for_response,
WC_REST_Orders_V2_Controller->get_formatted_item_data,
WC_Order->get_base_data, WC_Order->get_order_number,
apply_filters('woocommerce_order_number'),
WP_Hook->apply_filters,
WC_Seq_Order_Number_Pro->get_order_number,
WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get,
wc_doing_it_wrong.
This message was added in version 3.0.
```

The IP address is redacted but the error is related to the way how the order ID is requested by the REST API? After that, I get a bit hazy following the rest. Just so I am clear, I have absolutely no control over the way the Webhook works or is coded. What I do need to do is go to someone, be it WooCommerce (unlikely) or to DEAR, and ask them to resolve this. Overall, is this something I need to even worry about?

As an aside, I can say that the site works perfectly, with no other errors of note. This one is pretty much all I see in my logs.

Many thanks.

Comment: It means that you are accessing the id property of an object directly and not through a method. Try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231684/order-properties-should-not-be-accessed-directly-woocommerce-3-0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385920/woocommerce-get-current-product-id

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoDiGaetano - is being generated by the IP address that I redacted? Thats the way I would interpret this?

Comment: [Here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) you can find documentation on Apache log files. The client IP address refers to the server that generated the error.